# Error in logcat, while working with Android PHP and JSON,

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I have a php file which is returning JSON Array and here is my code to connect to that php and fetching response in jsonArray.
Is it correct ?

JSON Response From PHP

**[{"id":"1","name":"Swapnil","age":"21","address":"Nerul","mobile":"4475478983"}]**

**activity_main.xml**

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display All"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.lnt.swapnil;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button sendButton;
    private TextView displayTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        PHPConnector obj = new PHPConnector();
       JSONArray myArray =  obj.getAll();
        setDisplayTextView(myArray);
    }

    public void setDisplayTextView(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        String s = "";

        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s + "Id : "+jsonObject.getString("id")+"\n\n"
                        + "Name : "+jsonObject.getString("name")+"\n\n"
                        + "Age : "+jsonObject.getString("age")+"\n\n"
                        + "Address : "+jsonObject.getString("address")+"\n\n"
                        + "Mobile : "+jsonObject.getString("mobile")+"\n\n";
                displayTextView.setText(s);

            }
            catch (JSONException exp)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}




******************************************************************************


 package com.lnt.swapnil;

    import android.util.Log;

    import org.json.JSONArray;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    /**
     * Created by SWAPNIL on 20-08-2015.
     */
    public class PHPConnector {
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

        public JSONArray getAll()
        {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Android/test.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
            Log.i("Exception : ",e.getMessage());

        }
            return jsonArray;
        }
    }

***************************************************************************

**GetMember.java**

package com.lnt.swapnil;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;

/**
 * Created by SWAPNIL on 20-08-2015.
 */
public class GetMembers extends AsyncTask<PHPConnector,Long,JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(PHPConnector... phpConnectors) {
        return phpConnectors[0].getAll();
    }


}
```

---

** manifest.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lnt.swapnil" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

** Log Cat **

```
 Process: com.lnt.swapnil, PID: 2288
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
            at com.lnt.swapnil.PHPConnector.getAll(PHPConnector.java:40)
            at com.lnt.swapnil.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-21 23:00:10.317    2288-2295/com.lnt.swapnil W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 44.072ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
```

after

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Android/test.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: can u tell me, at which line you are getting the exception. Also edited my answer

Comment: on below link I have update my code kindly have a look.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8WzjXJJI6EjZmpxdDFnNnExM2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please edit the question here, there is no problem in editing question here

Comment: I am getting exception at two points
at line 30 of PHPConnector.java
         urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
And then in MainActivity.java

PHPConnector obj = new PHPConnector();
obj.getAll();